# How to avoid doing two separate passes while querying through a table?

Tags: sql-server, performance

The context of this problem are hospital visits. The logic is a bit convoluted but these are the requirements.

- Table Visits contains the names and visitIDs for the patients.
- Table FilteredVisits contains certain visits that meet some criteria

The report is run under a certain date range - this is important. Let's assume 1/1/2013 to 1/31/2013

- If a visit exists in FilteredVisits during that date range, the
  report shows a 1 for that visit. Else, it returns 0.
- However, if there exists an entry for that Patient (Name1) in FilteredVisits prior to the date range (before 1/1/2013 in our
  example), then **ALL** the visits for that patient need to be 1,
  regardless if the other visits don't exist in FilterVisits table.
- PatientID and VisitID are both unique values.
- the report only outputs patients and visits within the date range

See below for an example.

Currently, the code is doing 2 separate updates (2 passes) to a temp table that is storing the results. One update to set the value to 0/1 for the date range selected and then another update where is searches everything prior to the begin date parameter. The FilteredVisits table can be large, is there a way to optimize this to be faster?

Table1 All Patient Visits

```
PatientNameID VisitID
-------------------

PatientName1 P1Visit1
PatientName1 P1Visit2
PatientName1 P1Visit3
PatientName2 P2Visit1
PatientName3 P3Visit1
PatientName3 P3Visit2
```

Table2 Filtered Visits

```
PatientNameID  VisitID  Date
-------------------------
PatientName1 P1Visit1    12/1/2012
PatientName1 P1Visit3    1/2/2013
PatientName3 P3Visit1    1/8/2013
```

The results:

```
Results
PatientName1 P1visit1   1
PatientName1 P1visit2   1 -- would be '0' but there was a visit by PatientName1 BEFORE the date range so set to 1
PatientName1 P1visit3   1
PatientName2 P2visit1   0
PatientName3 P3visit1   1
PatientName3 P3Visit2   0 -- this stays 0 because there is no entry of PatientName3 visit3 in table2 and no visit by PatientName3 prior to the selected date range
```

-- Edit: TempTable includes only the patients and visits for the selected date range

```
-- First  pass
UPDATE t
SET MeasureIsTrue = 1
FROM TempTable t
INNER JOIN FilteredVisits fv ON fv.visitID = t.visitID 

-- Second pass      
UPDATE t
SET MeasureIsTrue = 1
FROM TempTable t
INNER JOIN FilteredVisits fv ON fv.PatientID = t.PatientID -- join on patientID to include all visits
        AND fv.visitDate < @BeginDate -- search only before date range
```

Comment: This would be much clearer if you actually provided the code that makes the two passes.

Comment: @JefferyKhan Added 'Update code'. From memory, I don't have the code in front of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one pass:

```
UPDATE t
SET MeasureIsTrue = 1
FROM TempTable t
INNER JOIN FilteredVisits fv ON
 (fv.PatientID = t.PatientID -- join on patientID to include all visits
    AND fv.visitDate < @BeginDate) -- search only before date range
 OR (fv.visitID = t.visitID)
```

Although, I would not mind two passes in this case as it does not appear to be a performance issue and it works either way.  Up to the developer.

Or... are you looking for this:

```
UPDATE t
SET MeasureIsTrue = 1
FROM TempTable t
INNER JOIN FilteredVisits fv ON fv.visitID = t.visitID
WHERE
 fv.PatientID = t.PatientID -- join on patientID to include all visits
    AND fv.visitDate < @BeginDate -- search only before date range
```

Upon review, I think you are looking for a LEFT JOIN between the Patients and Visits tables with summary information.  SUM or COUNT or maybe a CASE WHEN VisitDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END with a GROUP BY PatientName.

Comment: The former is what I'm looking for. I think that should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t
SET MeasureIsTrue = 1
FROM TempTable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN FilteredVisits fv1 ON fv1.visitID = t.visitID
LEFT OUTER JOIN FilteredVisits fv2 ON fv2.PatientID = t.PatientID
WHERE fv1.visitID is not null
   OR fv2.visitDate < @BeginDate -- search only before date range
```